# How to trigger a function onAwait of a CompletableDeferred<String>?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to index an image when it is created.  I thought it would be as easy as:

```
val saveLocation = CompletableDeferred<String>()
saveLocation.onAwait { loc:String ->
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationContext, arrayOf(loc), null, null)
}
```

But it says `Expression onAwait of type SelectClause1<String> cannot be invoked as a function` so maybe I'm using it wrong?  Is there a way to register a function to be called when the CompletableDeferred finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onAwait` is a property which returns `SelectClause1<T>`

So you would use something like this

```
val clause = saveLocation.onAwait
clause.registerSelectClause1( // your args here)
```

But, if you want the result of the deferred why don't you just start a coroutine and call `await`?

```
launch {
  val result = saveLocation.await()
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationContext, arrayOf(result), null, null)
}
```

Comment: *Forehead-slap* yes that is way easier.  Thank you!